What's happening on Bitcoin.SE in 2015?
What's moderation actions have been taken on Bitcoin.SE in 2015?

December 24th

Burninated start.

December 22nd

Updated Canonical question for "Unconfirmed transactions": Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?

November 11th
Sorry, I forgot to post intermittenly.

Added tags for cloud-mining, cex.io, ghash.io.
Created Canonical question for "Getting started with mining questions":
In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?

September 8th

Got in touch with Ethereum proposal, to point out that Ethereum questions are on-topic on Bitcoin.SE.

August 20th

Slightly improved I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing? to provide a Canonical Question for the common issue of "My payment didn't arrive, because I'm still synchronizing.".
Slightly improved What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?, edited and linked a bunch of closely related questions to it.
Ended up looking over most of the questions tagged with synchronization, editing a bunch of them and closing a lot of duplicates.
Started a list of canonical questions.

July 28th

I've just added a small section to the help section of Bitcoin.SE titled "New to Bitcoin?" with some pointers to resources and introductory concepts.
Feedback concerning action and selection of links welcome!

July 21st

Created bequesting-bitcoin to collect questions about leaving cryptocurrency assets to your bereaved.

June 25th

Merged and synonymized block-solution-time into block-interval. Added the tag to a bunch of questions that didn't have it yet, but clearly should.

June 21st

Merged and synonymized bitcoin-qt into bitcoin-core.

June 17th

Added loans to collect questions about lending, borrowing, and loans denominated in Bitcoin.

June 9th

Added majority-attack to collect questions about 51%-attacks. Started tagging the respective questions with the tag (up to now 33). Sorry for the flood on the mainpage.

June 2nd

Merged target into difficulty.  


Reasoning: target And difficulty had been collecting the same topic of questions

improved the wiki excerpt for difficulty.
Merged payments into payment.

